# Trying to dateAdd with Moment.js and getting odd results

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a very basic loop

```
console.log(thisStart);
console.log(thisEnd);
console.log(thisDate);
while(checkcounter < 10){
    console.log(checkcounter);
    thisDate = moment(thisDate,'MM/DD/YYYY').add(1,'days').toDate('MM/DD/YYYY');
    console.log(thisDate);
    checkcounter++;
}
```

I would expect that to give me the next day formated MM/DD/YYYY but instead the first iteration IS the next day but then it jumps 6 months.

Being a new moment.js user I am not sure where I am going wrong

[image]

Comment: `.toDate()` outputs a JavaScript `Date`, not a `string`.  the `'MM/DD/YYYY'` will be ignored, and when you try to parse this on the second iteration, it's not a string in the format `'MM/DD/YYYY'`, so the second iteration will yield unexpected results.

Comment: I think you want to use `.format()` instead of `.toDate()` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the statement inside the loop:

```
thisDate = moment(thisDate,'MM/DD/YYYY').add(1,'days').toDate('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

The first error is to pass a format string to the `moment` constructor when the first argument is a `Date` object. [As described here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), you need to pass a format string only if the first argument is a string containing a date:

```
thisDate = moment(thisDate).add(1,'days').toDate('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

The `add` invocation is correct but the `doDate` one is not. The function `toDate` [does not take in input a format string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/):

```
thisDate = moment(thisDate).add(1,'days').toDate();
```

Here the complete snippet of code:

```js
var thisDate = new Date(),
    checkcounter = 0;

console.log('Init:', thisDate);
while (checkcounter < 10) {
    console.log('Check counter:', checkcounter);
    thisDate = moment(thisDate).add(1, 'days').toDate();
    console.log('thisDate:', thisDate);
    checkcounter++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
```